# Set of Convergence for the following Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

What is the set of convergence for this series: $ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{3^{\sqrt{n}}(2+i-3z)^n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} $ ? My initial thought was to use, $ \dfrac{1}{R} = \lim(|a_n|)^{1/n}$, but this left me with $ 2+i-3z = \dfrac{1}{R} $ and I do not think this is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put, $2+i-3z=p$. Then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{\sqrt n}(2+i-3z)^n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{\sqrt n}p^n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_np^n$$ where $a_n=\frac{3^{\sqrt n}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$.

Now, $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=3^{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\frac{{n^2+1}}{(n+1)^2+1}}\to1\text{ as } n\to \infty$$.

So radius of convergence is $1$ and domain of convergence is $|2+i-3z|<1$.

Answer (score 2):

First, we can try to find the $Z$'s such that the series 
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{3^{\sqrt{n}}Z^n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

converges. If $|Z|\geqslant 1$, then the term $3^{\sqrt{n}}Z^n /\sqrt{n^2+1}$ does not converge to $0$. 
If $|Z|< 1$, then the root test show that the series $S$ is convergent.